# How to prove this integral identity?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Define $\epsilon_k(x) = \epsilon(x+z_k) \chi_k(x+z_k).$ Then 
$$\int |\nabla \epsilon_k|^2 = \int |\nabla \epsilon|^2 \chi_k^2 - \int \epsilon^2 (\Delta \chi_k) \chi_k.$$
There is a complicated defintion of $\chi_k$ and $\epsilon$ but I don't think that it is required in proving the above identity. Here is what I have tried so far,
$$|\nabla \epsilon_k|^2 = (\nabla \epsilon \chi_k + \epsilon \nabla \chi_k)^2 = |\nabla \epsilon|^2 \chi_k^2 + \epsilon^2 |\nabla \chi_k|^2 + 2\epsilon \nabla \epsilon \chi_k \nabla \chi_k.$$
I am not sure how to simplify this further. Any hints will be much appreciated.

For the sake of completeness here is the definition of $\chi_k$ for $k=1,2.$ First we define $\chi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ to be a smooth function such that 
$$\chi = 1\text{ on } [0,1],\quad \chi = 0 \text{ on }[2,\infty], \quad \chi'\leq 0 \text{ on }\mathbb{R}.$$
Next,
$$\chi_1(x) = \chi\left(\frac{|x-z_1|}{\lambda}\right),\quad \chi_2(x) = (1-\chi_1(x))^{1/2}$$
for $\lambda = |z|/4\gg 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\nabla \cdot (\epsilon^2\chi_k\nabla \chi_k)=2\epsilon\chi_k\nabla\chi_k\cdot\nabla \epsilon+\epsilon^2\nabla\chi_k\cdot\nabla\chi_k+\epsilon^2\chi_k\Delta\chi_k,$$ and so

$$|\nabla\epsilon_k|^2=|\nabla \epsilon|^2 \chi_k^2 + \epsilon^2 |\nabla \chi_k|^2 + 2\epsilon \nabla \epsilon \chi_k \nabla \chi_k=|\nabla \epsilon|^2 \chi_k^2 +\nabla \cdot (\epsilon^2\chi_k\nabla \chi_k)-\epsilon^2\chi_k\Delta\chi_k.$$ Integrating both sides and using the divergence theorem gives what you're after.

Comment: I read about the divergence theorem, but I am not sure why the integral of the term $\nabla \cdot (\epsilon^2 \chi_k \nabla \chi_k)$ is equal to $0.$ Could you please give some indication?

Comment: @nls Well, I now see after your edit that they're all functions on $\mathbb{R}$, not higher dimensional (which makes the $\nabla$ notation a bit strange...). In $\mathbb{R},$ it's just regular integration by parts. If I'm understanding the definition properly, $\chi_k$'s are compactly supported, so they vanish on the boundary, which eliminates that term.

Comment: Actually, looking again, what I wrote in my previous comment will only be true for $\chi_1,$ not $\chi_2.$ I didn't read the definitions carefully enough. However, for $\chi_2,$ the same argument as in the post follows through. You'll be integrating on some region $(-\infty,-\alpha)\cup (\alpha,\infty).$ The support will make it so that $\chi_2$ will be zero at $\pm\alpha$, and since it will equal $1$ at both $\pm\infty,$ these will cancel each other out. So, the term still vanishes!